# Summer Solstice Spurious Correlations Challenge

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, curated-data

I came across [this hilarious web site](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations) that has charts of bizarre "correlations" between disparate categories. Results like this:

[image]

In the spirit of my *summer solstice shedding spuriously earned rep. campaign*, I pose the challenge of creating a small app. using Mathematica and its built-in data sources (and optionally use of external non-Wolram web data resources) to allow the user to select from various categories of data and have spurious correlations discovered and plotted in a similar fashion.

I'll be adding a *500 rep. points* bounty as soon as the system allows, to be awarded either automagically by the system to the highest voted response, or picked by me.

Let the games begin...

Comment: If you want to keep awarding these huge bounties you better start posting non-CW answers my friend. :-)

Comment: Do Wall Street curves qualify as "spurious correlations"?

Comment: @belisarius: Anything goes, so long as it follows the disparate category concept - so stock price of Oracle vs age of Larry Ellison's temporally proximal girlfriend works... ;=}

Comment: Is there a minimum value of Pearson's $r$ needed to qualify for the dubious honor? :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: No, but I suppose the discovered "correlations" should display the *r*, and discovery would ideally "hunt" for high *r*...

Comment: I say good luck with `ExampleData["Statistics"]` as there is no common data format of the data in there. You actually have to read the description and/or column headers to determine how time was recorded. You could find some success with the machine learning and the grammar functions to assist; I think. I've not the time to delve into that.

Comment: @ciao I do love this idea...though I have just passed Winter Solstice...( I particularly like the http://image.slidesharecdn.com/quantitativesynthesisii-100719141934-phpapp01/95/quantitative-synthesis-ii-23-728.jpg?cb=1279549307 )...I hope people have time to play...I am a little time poor

Comment: I find this a funny challenge, but after investing a few minutes I came to realize that finding a good datasource (or a set of them) is boring and time consuming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, despite the many up-votes, more than 100 days have past and no one has found it interesting enough post a answer.